# How to pass the focus state to View's parent?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can a view detect its child view's focus state? As you can see in this picture.
[image]

The parent view is a `LinearLayout` with a child view `EditText`. I wanna change the UI while the focus state changed(linearlayout turns red if focus on the edittext). But only the `EditText` can detect the focus state while the `LinearLayout` can not. Of cause I can listen the `EditText`'s state using `OnFocusChangedListrner`. But I don't satisfy with it. Is there a simple way to make the parent view get the child view's focus event? The form has a lot of items.

Comment: i don't think there is another method other than onfocuschanged

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I also think there is no other method than

```
onfocusChangeListner
```

If you have many edittext then you simply make one method with the parameter and inside it you write only one `onfocuschangeListner` like this

```
public void setColorToEditText(EditText editText) {
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            Log.e("userFocu", "userFocu");
            if (!hasFocus) {
                // code to execute when EditText loses focus

            }
        }
 });
```

Comment: it's too complex that I've to deal with every item. Maybe I can only write a custom view. I'm navie.